genSourceMapUrl - Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
I am not the greatest at node build issues.
 ERROR  Internal server error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters                                                                                                         1:40:30 PM  
      at Object.slice (node:buffer:670:37)
      at Uint8Array.toString (node:buffer:840:14)
      at genSourceMapUrl (file:///M:/source/AdvancedStorageV3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:20802:59)
      at getCodeWithSourcemap (file:///M:/source/AdvancedStorageV3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:20812:24)
      at send (file:///M:/source/AdvancedStorageV3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:62049:17)
      at viteTransformMiddleware (file:///M:/source/AdvancedStorageV3/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CzJTQ5q7.js:62180:18)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

How do I start debugging this?
For starter, how do I determine:

Is this an internal build a error, that is happening despite my code?
Is this a code issue, that is causing me to have a large chunck.

